# Degenerated Differential Pair voltage headroom

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, differential, small-signal

I was reading about ways to make the differential gain linear by adding degenerative resistors Rs as shown, but it has voltage swing limitations, having swing reduced by Is*Rs( when one of the MOS reaches cutoff)

[image]

So there is another topology for swing limitation problem, which is

[image]

My question is how is the ss gain and swing different in this topology and how to analyze the large and ss model gain. How about power consumption?

My approach is-

1. first apply miller theorem, but I'm not sure how to break the 2Rs. Suppose we get Rs each side, so I have ss model where Rs and Rd (parallel with a near-infinite current source, Hence system has Av= Rd/Rs( CS degeneration case)
2. Now in large-signal, the output can go max Vcc and regarding min value, I believe it'll be (Vgs-Vt) + Vov(overdrive), around 0.25+0.25 = 0.5 V, but We have Rs as well, there will be some V drop across R(say 0.5V) hence, certainly Vs must be 0.5 volt, then net Vomin = 1V. I know I'm wrong, please help me regarding the large signal to get the intuitive idea.

Comment: I'd suggest that you look at [this MC1496 analysis paper](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN531-D.PDF) on the [MC1496 device](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC1496-D.PDF). It may help.

Comment: @jonk I got to know the small signal model of the half circuit, which is equivalent to CS with regenerative load Rs, but additionally there is current source in parallel to Rs. I simulated it and found the gain is same as Rd/Rs, also swing being same(which should not be according to the text). Can you explain how normal CS with regenerative Rs different from this case wrt swing, power?